# C++, fstream, Reading from the file does not give correct result

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I am trying to create a simple program that writes inputted data to file and then reads that data from a file. For some reason the output is not correct. The first value that it reads from the file displays all three inputted values instead of just first one. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    double totalRainfall=0.0, highTemperature,lowTemperature, totalHigh=0.0, 
     totalLow=0.0;

// open a file in write mode.
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("statistics.txt");


    cout << "Enter total rainfall (in inches) : ";
    cin >> totalRainfall;
    outFile <<totalRainfall;  // write inputted data into the file.



    cout << "Enter high temperature (in Fahrenheit): ";
    cin >> highTemperature;
    outFile << highTemperature;  // write inputted data into the file.


    cout << "Enter low temperature (in Fahrenheit) : ";
    cin >> lowTemperature;
    outFile << lowTemperature;  // write inputted data into the file.

    //close the opened file
    outFile.close();

    //open a file in read mode.
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("statistics.txt");

    inFile >> totalRainfall; 
    cout << "The rainfall: ";
    cout<< totalRainfall<<endl; 

    inFile >> highTemperature;
    cout << "High temperature: ";
    cout << highTemperature<<endl;

    inFile >> lowTemperature;
    cout << "Low temperature: ";
    cout<<lowTemperature<<endl;

    // close the opened file.
    inFile.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no separation of items

Comment: How do I separate items?

Comment: Your question would be better if the code were shorter. Please read about [minimal, complete, and verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Maria You can output space between the items. Or newlines.

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: Please include the data file too. The problem may be there.

Comment: Have you tried to open the file with a text editor and look?

Answer (score 0):

You should put a separator between each output number in order to be able to know where a number starts and where it finish when reading the file. A whitespace character as a separator allow to read numbers without specific code to skip the separator (stl functions that read numbers skip leading whitespace characters).

Below an example with space as separator character:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char sep = ' ';
const char* const file_path = "statistics.txt";

int main()
{
    double value = 0.0;

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(file_path);

    cout << "Enter total rainfall (in inches): ";
    cin >> value;
    outFile << value << sep;

    cout << "Enter high temperature (in Fahrenheit): ";
    cin >> value;
    outFile << value << sep;

    cout << "Enter low temperature (in Fahrenheit): ";
    cin >> value;
    outFile << value;

    outFile.close();

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(file_path);

    inFile >> value;
    cout << "The rainfall: ";
    cout << value << endl;

    inFile >> value;
    cout << "High temperature: ";
    cout << value << endl;

    inFile >> value;
    cout << "Low temperature: ";
    cout << value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `write()` and `read()` methods of the fstream objects. Those methods allow you to write/read a specific number of bytes. So you could just create two utility functions like these:

```
void writeValue(ofstream& f, const double& v) {
    f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&v), sizeof(v));
}

void readValue(ifstream& f, double& v) {
    f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v), sizeof(v));
}
```

Now you can use them in your main code:

```
double value = 0.0;

ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(file_path);

cout << "Enter total rainfall (in inches): ";
cin >> value;
writeValue(outFile, value);

cout << "Enter high temperature (in Fahrenheit): ";
cin >> value;
writeValue(outFile, value);

cout << "Enter low temperature (in Fahrenheit): ";
cin >> value;
writeValue(outFile, value);

outFile.close();

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(file_path);

readValue(inFile, value);
cout << "The rainfall: ";
cout << value << endl;

readValue(inFile, value);
cout << "High temperature: ";
cout << value << endl;

readValue(inFile, value);
cout << "Low temperature: ";
cout << value << endl;
```

### Improving the read/write functions

The utility functions I mentioned above can handle only `double` values. This is not flexible and should be an issue if you want to expand your code and handle different types of information. So if you want to make your code more robust and allow other variable types (e.g, int, float) in the serialized file, you can use templates instead:

```
template<typename T>
void writeValue(ofstream& f, const T& v) {
    f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&v), sizeof(v));
}

template<typename T>
constexpr void readValue(ifstream& f, T& v) {
    f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v), sizeof(v));
}
```

If you also want to handle `std::string`, you can customize the templates for that specific type:

```
template<>
constexpr void writeValue(ofstream& f, const std::string& v) {
    auto len = v.length();
    f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
    f.write(v.c_str(), v.length() * sizeof(char));
}

template<>
void readValue(ifstream& f, std::string& v) {
    std::string::size_type len;
    f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&len), sizeof(len));

    char buffer[len + 1];
    f.read(buffer, len);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    v = buffer;
}
```